# SQL: Select based on related_id and related_table. ID's stored in array named for table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a table called activities that looks like this

---

### id | related_id | related_table | ...

And 3 arrays, each named after a table, containing ID's:

```
$clubs[1,2,3]; $vendors[4,5,6]; $users[7,8,9];
```

How do I select the activities that belong to the corresponding clubs, vendors, and users in the arrays? I only know very simple SQL, but am sure there is a way to do this.

I am looking to do this in 1 select statement, if possible. Otherwise I know how to do "where in" to do it in 3.

ANSWER:

Here is how I accomplished getting all the activites in 1 select:

```
'SELECT * from activities where (related_table = \'clubs\' and related_id in ('.$clubs_string.')) or  (related_table = \'vendors\' and related_id in ('.$vendors_string.')) or (related_table = \'users\' and related_id in ('.$users_string.'));';
```

See Morgan Wilde's answer about implode()-ing the arrays to strings.

Comment: Nice, although I'd use double quotes and {} to include variables inside the query string. Like so "SELECT *
FROM `activities`
WHERE
(related_table = 'clubs' and related_id in ({$clubs_string})) OR 
(related_table = 'vendors' and related_id in ({$vendors_string})) OR
(related_table = 'users' and related_id in ({$users_string}))";

Comment: I used to write sql that way, but my boss writes in this way and makes me do it this way too. Is there any advantage beyond being much easier to read (and write)?

Comment: Not in this case, just code hygiene. Single quotes force you to escape variables by interrupting the declaration with '..', where as double quotes interpret more unescaped symbols for their php meaning, like the dollar sign, so you'd be fine with "some $variable". Ease of use IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if I've got your question right, the way to find all activities that relate to club id's saved in an array should be...

```
$clubs_string = implode(",", $clubs); // convert your array into a comma separated string
```

Once you've got that sorted, send a query like

```
SELECT `id` FROM `activities` WHERE `related_id` IN ({$clubs_string}) AND `related_table` = 'club_table_name'
```

You can repeat the same logic for all other table types that you have.

Here you can find some neat MySQL WHERE IN examples - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Hope that helps!

Comment: So, you don't think it's possible in a single select, then? Thanks for the link.

Comment: Well this would constitute a single select. Unless you would like to count converting your array to a string as a select :? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: That is a single select, but it only got the 'club' activities. I'd like to get activities from all three tables in one select. It can be accomplished with OR. I'll update my question with how I accomplished it.

Comment: Oh sure, as I mentioned, you can add any other WHERE clauses. Follow up with your results, if any :)